# numpy vectorize a function to accepts vectors of different lengths and return the tensor result

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I want to vectorize a function `f(a, b)` so that, when I enter a and b as two vectors, the tensor of combinations is returned. Here is an illustrative example:

```
import numpy as np
def tester(a, b):
   mysumm = 0.
   for ii in range(a):
       for jj in range(b):
           mysumm += a * b
   return mysumm
tester = np.vectorize(tester)
x, y = [2, 4], [3, 5, 8] 
print(tester(x, 3)) # [ 36. 144.]
print(tester(x, 5)) # [100. 400.]
print(tester(x, 8)) # [ 256. 1024.]
print(tester(2, y)) # [ 36. 100. 256.]
print(tester(4, y)) # [ 144.  400. 1024.]
print(tester(x, y)) # ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)
```

I expected the `tester(x, y)` call to return a 2x3 matrix, something like `[[ 36. 100. 256.], [ 144.  400. 1024.]]` and I was surprised that this isn't the default behavior.

How can I make the vecotirzed function return the tensor of possible combinations of the input vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain with `np.ix_`:

```
>>> import functools
>>> 
>>> def tensorize(f):
...     fv = np.vectorize(f)
...     @functools.wraps(f)
...     def ft(*args):
...         return fv(*np.ix_(*map(np.ravel, args)))
...     return ft
... 
>>> tester = tensorize(tester)
>>> tester(np.arange(3), np.arange(2))
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 4.]])
```

Comment: Thanks for this nice answer. The code works. Would you be willing to explain why this isn't the default behavior of `np.vectorize` and/or how `np.ix_`  is similar/different to `np.vectorize`?

Comment: @kilojoules the default behavior throughout numpy would be broadcasting; this has the advantage of being an amazingly well working compromise between simplicity and expressiveness. The "tensor" example I'd say all but confirms this. `ix_` and `vectorize` do fundamentally different things, `vectorize` applies a function, `ix_` just reshapes vectors to form a broadcastable open grid. I recommend you look at the output of `ix_` to get a feeling for how it works.