# Creating Matrices as Dyadic Products of Vectors

Tags: python

I am given two vectors **u** and **v** of length **m** and **n** and want to create from them a matrix **A** with **m** rows and **n** columns as a generalized `dyadic product` of **u** and **v**, i.e.
    `A[i][j] = f(u[i],v[j])`;

Is there already a `boilerplate` solution for that kind of matrix generation available in `Python`, e.g. in `NumPy`, `resp.`, what would be the "most pythonic" way of solving it?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50339627/7207392) what you looking for?

Comment: @PaulPanzer yes, that seems to solve my problem; unfortunately its not a builtin solution.

Comment: Ok, let's leave it open for a bit to see whether somebody comes up with a better answer, but at some point we'll have to mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meanwhile found that meshgrid fits my bill.

A distance table for five points with random coordinates can be generated as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import random as rnd
x=[rnd.random() for i in range(5)] # x-coordinates of the points
y=[rnd.random() for i in range(5)] # y-coordinates of the points
xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(x,x)        # for x-differences
yy1, yy2 = np.meshgrid(y,y)        # for y-differences
d = np.sqrt((xx2-xx1)**2+(yy2-yy1)**2)  # creates the distance table
```

The distance matrix can also be generated by a one-liner:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
y = np.array([2,4,6,8])

dist = np.sqrt(np.subtract.outer(x,x)**2 + np.subtract.outer(y,y)**2)
```